# Arraylist help required

Tags: java, jgrasp

```
import java.util.*;
public class Election {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //ArrayList<String> Declaration
    ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<String>();
    //add method for String ArrayList
    al.add("Mike Doherty");
    al.add("Joan Murphy");
    al.add("Marie Smith");
    al.add("George Jones");

      System.out.println("ArrayList before remove:");
       for(String var: al){
        System.out.println(var);
   }
   //Removing 1st element
   al.remove(1);

      System.out.println("ArrayList After remove:");
    for(String var2: al){
         System.out.println(var2);
       }
        //adding a new element
    al.add("Tom Carroll");

        System.out.println("ArrayList After new name:");
            for(String var3: al){
                System.out.println(var3);

  } 

}
}
```

the above code does what it is supposed to do but not the way i would like.

What i want it to do is print out the first four names i.e Mike Doherty to George Jones. (this i can do)

However what i want to be able to do is allow the user to enter a candidate to remove i.e Joan Murphy and allow the user to enter a new candidate to add i.e Tom Carroll.

Then finally i want to print out the results with Joan Murphy removed and Tom Carroll added.

The way i have done it does work but i don't know how to do it by letting the user remove a name and enter a name.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: al.remove(1); will remove second element. index starts from zero

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you're looking for is "remove by value", not by index.

```
al.remove("Mike Doherty");
```

Replace "Mike Doherty" with a string taken as user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reader to get user input for removal like:

```
`System.out.println("Please enter the candidate name you wish to remove: ");    
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String toBeRemoved = br.readLine();
al.remove(toBeRemoved);`
```

Then you add a person the same way:

```
`System.out.println("Please enter the candidate name you wish to add: ");    
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String toBeAdded = br.readLine();
al.add(toBeRemoved);`
```

Since items in the list are strings, you can remove them by passing their value to the `remove` method of the list.